Chronology \eventpoint \eventspan undefined control sequence in overleaf
I'm getting a strange error with chronology latex package that two of its key commands \eventspan \eventpoint are undefined. I'm also encountering this error when I use code directly from their documentation page (linked). Here's the exact code I'm running where my only additions are setting the document class and the \begin{document} \end{document} statements. Note that I'm using Overleaf and the \event command works fine, so I don't think it's an issue with the package installing.
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{chronology}


\begin{document}

\begin{chronology}[5]{1965}{2023}{\textwidth}[100ex]
\eventpoint{1963}{PDP-5}[red][1][1]
\eventspan {\decimaldate{1}{8}{1969}}{\decimaldate{31}{8}{2023}}%
{\textbf{\color{blue}Unix}}[blue][.3][2][b]
\eventpoint{\decimaldate{11}{4}{1976}}{Launch of Apple I}[red][1][1]
\eventpoint{\decimaldate{12}{8}{1981}}{Launch of IBM PC}[red][1][1]
\eventpoint{\decimaldate{15}{9}{1993}}{Debian 0.01}[red][1][1]
\eventpoint{\decimaldate{26}{10}{2004}}{Ubuntu 4.10}[red][1][1]
\eventspan {\decimaldate{25}{8}{1991}}{\decimaldate{31}{8}{2023}}%
{\textbf{\color{orange}Linux}}[orange][.6][.6][b]
\end{chronology}


\end{document}

https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chronology/chronology.pdf

welcome! your code compiles fine for me. (texlive 2024)

works fine for me in overleaf, too. are you sure you have 2024 configured for compilation? click on the menu at the top left and make sure 2024 is chosen from the drop-down menu. I can only reproduce the error with an older version (which is unsurprising).

if that's not the trouble, open the raw log file and paste it as text into your question.
